# SQL Trigger Update Average

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, average

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to make a trigger on Oracle SQL... 
Here is my problem : 
- I have a table X that contains values 0-10 and a table Y that contains the Average of this values for a group of X IDs. So I have to make a trigger that recalculate the average of the ID I'm inserting deleting or updating.
What basically im doing and failling... :

```
CREATE or REPLACE trigger Update_Average
    after insert or update or delete on X

DECLARE 
    holdID X.ID%type;
    Avrg Y.Average%type;

BEGIN
    holdID := X.ID;

    select avg(value)
      into Avrg
      from X 
      where X.id = holdID;

    update Y
       set Average = Avrg
       where Y.id = holdID;

END;
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff, it's oracle. have edited to include that tag.

Comment: Looks like you got a helpful answer already.  However, you should know that if `x` has concurrent updates, I expect `y` to end up with inconsistent values. This sort of trigger is very tricky to get right.  I'd be curious to see if others expect the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just do:

```
begin
    update Y
        set average = (select avg(value) from x where x.id = :new.id)
        where y.id = :new.id;
end
```

EDIT:

Oracle is fussy about updating tables that are being modified in a trigger.  Personally, I think I would avoid this problem by storing two values in `Y` -- the sum and the count.  Then, the trigger would look like:

```
begin
    update Y
        set sum = (sum + (case when :new.id is not null then :new.value else 0 end) -
                   (case when :old.id is not null then :old.value else 0 end))
            cnt = (cnt + (case when :new.id is not null then 1 else 0 end) -
                   (case when :old.id is not null then 1 else 0 end))
        where y.id = :new.id;
end
```

Note: for the ease of putting this in one statement, this checks the values for `NULL`, rather than using `if DELETING`.  I'm pretty sure Oracle returns `NULL` for things like the `:NEW` record in a delete trigger.

Comment: That doesn't look quite right.  `x` doesn't have an `average` column.

Comment: I must've seen that while you were writing the comment.

Comment: I added a comment for OP, but would be interested in your opinion.  Don't you think that this sort of trigger is vulnerable to concurrent updates on `x`?  Seems to me like 2 concurrent updates in different transactions on different rows of `x` can end up corrupting the computed value on `y`. If you agree, perhaps your post will be even more helpful if it adds a word of warning about that.

Comment: If you're doing anything other than an `insert ... values`, that would generate a mutating table exception.  Since the goal is to query other rows in the table being modified, you'd need both row- and statement-level triggers or one compound trigger with row- and statement-level sections.